# Why does my Perl/Tk button widget size vary with different xterm clients?

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

I have a Perl/Tk script in which I am creating a button widget of height 1.
Now when I execute script through Citrix xterm client I get button displayed. 
Again when I execute script now through xterm client in my PC size of button widget differs.
Can someone explain why is this happening, and what should I do so that size of button widget remains constant with different xterm clients?

Comment: can you show us a minimal source example, plz?

Comment: Can you take some screenshots and show us how different these buttons look?

Answer (score 0):

Tk uses an "option database" that determines the default appearance of widgets. That database (typically a file named `.Xdefaults`) can vary for different machines or different users on the same machine. In general you shouldn't worry about this because it allows the user to set their own preferences for fonts, colors, etc. The alternative is to fully specify the options for each widget and not use default values for anything.